# How to compare two strings and ignoring words that are between quotes?

Tags: c#, regex, string, compare

I have two strings as follows :

```
string s1=@"hello my name is ""othden"" can I meet you";
string s2=@"hello my name is can I meet you";
```

I want to find s2 in s1 so the result should return true (Which means that I found `s2` in `s1`) ignoring the `"othden"` because it is inside quotes. How can I make this search while ignoring part of string?

Comment: please provide some more details, whether string ""othden"" will be always  covered with "", also please show code up to which you tried.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove `"othden"` or `""othden""`? Per your requirement, you will never match ignoring `"othden"`. Please be a little more clear.

Comment: I want s1 to stay as is with no modification or replacement. so when I search s2 in s1 it should ignore the "othden" word or any other text between quotes. in my application it should treat s1=s2.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all occurences of these cases, and create a whole new normalized string (just to keep the original).

Then you would only need to use the normalized string for any comparisons you may want to make.

```
string s1 = @"hello my name is ""othden"" can I meet you";
string s2 = "hello my name is can I meet you";
string normalized_s1 = Regex.Replace(s1, "\"[^\"]*\"", String.Empty);
bool areEquals = (s2 == normalized_s1);
```

The regex `\"[^\"]*\"` means the following:

1. `\"` matches the character `"` literally.
2. `[^\"]` matches any character that is not `"`

   2.a. `*` between **zero** and **unlimited** times.
3. `\"` matches the character `"` literally

Comment: @stribizhev You're absolutely right. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A little unclear on what you want, but something like this should do it.

```
        string s1=@"hello my name is ""othden"" can I meet you";
        string s2=@"hello my name is can I meet you";

        string temp = s1.Replace(" \"othden\"", String.Empty);

        bool b = s2.Contains(temp);
```

You can't necessarily just "ignore" part of a string, instead you need to make a new, 'temp' string that does not contain the values you know are not important.

If you're looking to ignore *anything* in between the quotes then you'd want something like this:

```
        string s1=@"hello my name is ""othden"" can I meet you";
        string s2=@"hello my name is can I meet you";

        int fqi = s1.IndexOf('"');
        int lqi = s1.LastIndexOf('"');

        string temp = s1.Remove(fqi, (lqi - fqi));
        temp = temp.Replace("\" ", String.Empty);

        bool b = s2.Contains(temp);
```

Comment: think he means ignoring anything between quotes in a string, not just a hard code fix

Comment: Well he didn't say that. Then just `String.IndexOf()` to find the beginning & ending quotes, and replace the value in that range. I answered the question asked, not what he might mean.

Comment: I want the first string to still as is, not modified, I want to search s2 in s1 ignoring any words between quotes.

Comment: Editted to ignore whatever's been the quotes. It's pretty sloppy and has lots of room for improvement though.